# Yocto project : How can I connect my Embedded SAMA5D27 microchip board to WIFI network?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, atmel, microchip

I am using SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK1 embedded board.

I build for it Linux distribution using Yocto project following the steps described here :

[Yocto_Linux_Kernel](https://www.linux4sam.org/bin/view/Linux4SAM/Sama5d27Som1EKMainPage)

I can connect my board with the Ethernet port and it's working. But I want to connect to network using WIFI instead of Ethernet.

I don't find how to do that. Help me please! Thank you!